# How to load icon with V3 Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to load an icon with my chrome extension, but when I try to unpack my extension, I get an error saying the following:
"Could not load icon '../src/assets/images/checkmark-16.png' specified in 'icons'."

Below is my manifest. Does anyone know that I am doing wrong?

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Reminder-App",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Reminder app for all your tasks",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "Reminder App"
  },
   "icons": {
   "16": "../src/assets/images/checkmark-16.png"
 },
  "permissions": ["storage"]
}
```

Comment: the manifest file must be inside the root of your extension folder and your icon must NOT be outside that folder. Try to cut ../

Comment: The paths in manifest are relative to the output directory (dist), not src, so if you use a build system you need to configure it to copy the files from src explicitly.